# The meaning of " let go from the shoulther "

Tags: meaning

‘“My troth,” sez I, “you’ve lived too long—you an’ your seekin’s an’ findin’s in a dacint married woman’s quarters! Hould up your head, ye frozen thief av Genesis,” sez I, “an’ you’ll find all you want an’ more!”

‘But he niver hild up, an’ **I let go from the shoulther to where the hair is short over the eyebrows.**
‘“That’ll do your business,” sez I, but it nearly did mine instid. I put me bodyweight behind the blow, but I hit nothing at all, an’ near put me shoulther out. The Corp’ril man was not there,

This is from "The Solid Muldoon " by Rudyard Kipling.
https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/the-solid-muldoon.htm

I don't understand the meaning of
I let go from the shoulther to where the hair is short over the eyebrows.

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Comment: Have you read through the rest of the story, and understood all the Irish dialect, and British Indian Army slang???

Comment: **I let go** presumably means "I [let fly](https://www.lexico.com/definition/let_fly)." (Once again I am amazed to see you reading such difficult English!)

Answer (score 3):

It appears to mean "I let go" = I released a punch,  "from the shoulther" = a with a full swing of the arm from the shoulder (with eye-dialect spelling). "to where the hair is short over the eyebrows" = aimed at the temples.

That is it means "I punched him hard in the head"

Comment: thank you very much for your precise and helpful answer!!

Answer (score 2):

From the subsequent sentence, it appears that Mulvaney attempted to punch the Corporal on the forehead - 'put his weight behind the blow'.